# What is the difference between "Doko de benkyou shiteiru no desu ka?" and "Doko de benkyou benkyo shiteimasu ka?"

Tags: grammar, particle-の

In Japanese, what is the difference between "Doko de benkyou shiteiru no desu ka?" (どこ で べんきょう している の です か?) and "Doko de benkyou benkyo shiteimasu ka?" (どこ で べんきょう べんきょ していますか?)

How does the different structure change the meaning? Please explain with reference to the two sentences.

Please note, I am still learning kana so please accept my apologies if there are errors in it. I am more interested in the meaning.

Comment: Where did you hear these sentences? The second one is nonsensical.

Comment: The べんきょ (not the べんきょう) in the second sentence is superfluous and is most certainly misspelled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to "A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar", page 325:
のだ: a sentence ending which indicates that the speaker is explaining or asking for an explanation about some information shared with the hearer, or is talking about something emotively.
The information is often what the speaker and the hearer have observed or heard.

どこで勉強しているのですか。
Where are you studying?
(The speaker already knows the hearer is studying and wants an explanation)

どこで勉強していますか。
Where are you studying?
(The speaker assumes the hearer is studying)